# Highlight element based on boolean pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have 2 data frames with identical indices/columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5.5, 3, 0, 3, 1],
                     'B':[2, 1, 0.2, 4, 5],
                     'C':[3, 1, 3.5, 6, 0]})

df_bool = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                          'B':[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                          'C':[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]})
```

I want to apply a style function to df element-wise using df_bool as a mask.

This is the expected result:

[image: expected results]

#### Current failed function

```
def color_boolean(val):
  color =''
  if df_bool == 1:
    color = 'red'
  elif df_bool == 0:
    color = 'black'
  return f'color: {color}'

df.head().style.apply(color_boolean, axis=None)
```

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function that ignores the input and simply uses the other DataFrame:

```
def color_boolean(val):
    return f'color: {"red" if val else "black"}'

df.style.apply(lambda _: df_bool.applymap(color_boolean), axis=None)
```

or:

```
df.style.apply(lambda c: df_bool[c.name].apply(color_boolean))
```

output:

[image: dataframe style]

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it!
I'm trying to also add on an additional condition (mode of column). 
```
def highlightMode(s):
    # Get mode of columns
    mode_ = s.mode().values
    # Apply style if the current value is mode
    return ['background-color: yellow' if v in mode_ else '' for v in s]
```
I'm a little confused on how to chain them together when one is using a separate df as a mask.
Appreciate any advice, thanks!

Comment: There are several options. A simple one might be to generate a DataFrame of the styles and then use this single one to apply them. Or use `numpy.select` with the many conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to convert `df_bool` into a DataFrame of styles based on the locations of `1` values (`df_bool.eq(1)`).

By setting `axis=None` to [Styler.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) we can effectively apply styles to the entire DataFrame.

```
true_css = 'color:red'
false_css = '' # No Styles (Change if needed)

df.style.apply(
    lambda _: np.where(df_bool.eq(1), true_css, false_css),
    axis=None
)
```

[image: Styled DataFrame with red colored text where df == 1 is True]

---

Optional [format](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html) to round and match shown output:

```
true_css = 'color:red'
false_css = ''

df.style.apply(
    lambda _: np.where(df_bool.eq(1), true_css, false_css),
    axis=None
).format(formatter='{:1g}')
```

[image: Styled DataFrame with red text including formatted rounding]

---

Imports (and versions):

```
import numpy as np  # 1.22.3
import pandas as pd  # 1.4.2
```